# LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types. (interface)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, casting

I have this code structure.

```
public interface IParentEquipment
{
    // attributes
}

[Table("TB_EQPT")]
public abstract class Equipment : IParentEquipment
{
   // attributes
}

[Table("TB_CAPACITOR")]
public class Capacitor : Equipment
{
   [Column("NAME")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm doing the following query on base:

```
public IList<IParentEquipment> FindAllEquipmentsBySubstationName(string name)
{
     List<IParentEquipment> equipments = new List<IParentEquipment>();

        // capacitor
     IQueryable<IParentEquipment> query = (
        from e in ((IAppContext)_ctx).Capacitor
        where e.Name.Equals(name)
        select e).Distinct().Cast<IParentEquipment>();
     equipments.AddRange(query.ToList());

     ....

    // more consultations of other equipment
 }
```

But I get the error:

> Unable to cast the type 'Models.Base.Equipments.Capacitor' to type
>   'Models.Base.Equipments.Interface.IParentEquipment'. LINQ to Entities
>   only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

My question is: Is it possible to cast **Capacitor** for **IParentEquipment** in this query? how to make?

Comment: Not without first materializing the results. `....Distinct().AsEnumerable().Cast<IParentEquipment>();`

Comment: Why do you want that cast?

Comment: @Igor What is the correct way to do this? thanks

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto Because I have different equipment, and I do not want to do many queries. =) Tks

Comment: But the class implements the interface, you don't need to cast... Unless you are hoping to join multiple `IQueryable<IParentEquipment>`? That won't work

Comment: @Igor Thanks, this solved my problem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to cast Capacitor for IParentEquipment in this query?

There is no need to do casting for this code to work.

```
var query = (
    from e in ((IAppContext)_ctx).Capacitor
    where e.Name.Equals(name)
    select e).Distinct();

 equipments.AddRange(query);
```

Comment: Is it really needed, though? Why not just `equipments.AddRange(query)`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - you're right, in this case it is not necessary at all.